# gtest: undefined reference to `operator+'

Tags: googletest

This is just an observation, but I don't understand where is the problem. I implement vector addition operator and everything is work pretty well in the main function. But when I tried to test it by Google Test I got the compilation error

```
In function `ZN15Basic_Dirs_Test8TestBodyEv':
C:/Users/home/Documents/clion/example/test/main.cpp:10: undefined reference
to `operator+(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&, 
std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
```

It compiles, however, when I remove src/class.cpp file. Could you tell me how it works? :)

The code is below.

src/class.h

```html
 #ifndef EXAMPLE_CLASS_H
 #define EXAMPLE_CLASS_H

 #include <vector>

 std::vector<int> operator+(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b);

 #endif //EXAMPLE_CLASS_H
```

src/class.cpp

```html
#include "class.h"

std::vector<int> operator+(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b) {
     if (a.size() != b.size()) {
         std::cerr << "vectors are not of the same size!\n";
         exit(1);
     }
     std::vector<int> res(a.size());
     for (unsigned i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
         res[i] = a[i] + b[i];
     }
     return res;
}
```

test/main.cpp

```html
#include "class.h"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

using namespace std;

TEST(Basic, Dirs) {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 1, 0};
    std::vector<int> b = {2, 1, 0};
    std::vector<int> c = a+b;
    EXPECT_EQ(c[0], 3);
    EXPECT_EQ(c[1], 2);
    EXPECT_EQ(c[2], 0);
}
```

./CMakeLists

```html
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(example)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp src/class.cpp)
add_subdirectory(test)
add_executable(example ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

test/CMakeLists

```html
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall")
add_subdirectory("../lib/googletest" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gtest_build")
include_directories(../lib/googletest/googletest/include)
include_directories(../src/)
add_executable(runtest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(runtest gtest gtest_main)
```

Comment: This looks more like CMakc question, but I think you have to add the class.cpp to the `test` like `add_executable(runtest main.cpp ../src/class.cpp)`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to link your `runtest` gtest executable against your `example`:

./CMakeLists

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(example)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp src/class.cpp)
add_executable(example ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_subdirectory(test)
```

test/CMakeLists

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall")
add_subdirectory("../lib/googletest" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gtest_build")
include_directories(../lib/googletest/googletest/include)
include_directories(../src/)
add_executable(runtest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(runtest gtest gtest_main example)
```

Also not that it might be better to actually define your `example` as a shared library instead of executable (just remove the `main` function - you probably don't need it anyway):

```
add_library(example SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
```